# How to continuously query a mongodb database efficiently

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Node and MongoDB and I have a seemingly simple request. I've managed to connect to my database, and use a query to get my desired results. Now, I want to have this query continue indefinitely, since the end goal for my project is to plot data real time.

I would have thought a simple 'while (true)' loop would suffice, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds157614.mlab.com:57614/flight_data';


// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {

  if (err) throw err;

  var dbo = db.db("flight_data").collection("data");

while(true)
{

    dbo.find().sort({_id: 1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err, result) {

    if (err) throw err;

    console.log("Temperature: " + result[0].data.temperature);

  });

}

db.close();

});
```

I have found that the while loop is indeed running, but for some reason, the query just doesn't happen when inside the while loop. If you remove the while loop, the code functions fine. I just want it to continually print the results of the query being repeated.

Comment: Instead of continuously hitting your database with queries in a while loop, I'd suggest looking into [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams) to efficiently watch for updates on the collection(s) of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying a DB continuously is inefficient and resource wasting, instead use [change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/). It watches collection for any changes and will make the db call then only. **Works only for Mongo 3.6+**.

```
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url =
  "mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds157614.mlab.com:57614/flight_data";

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  const collection = db.collection("data");
  const changeStream = collection.watch();
  changeStream.on("change", next => {
    // process next document
    collection
      .find()
      .sort({ _id: 1 })
      .limit(1)
      .toArray(function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log("Temperature: " + result[0].data.temperature);
      });
  });
  db.close();
});
```

Comment: I tried it and I'm getting some weird errors now. One of them is `MongoError: Majority read concern requested, but it is not supported by the storage engine.`

Comment: @JessieLSmith Which version of mongo are you using? Change Streams require MongoDB 3.6+.

Comment: It looks like I have 3.2.2 .  The newest version available for the node.js driver is 3.2.3. Will I need to figure out a different solution since I'm not using the mongo shell?

Comment: `The newest version available for the node.js driver is 3.2.3` What did you mean by that?  You must be confusing node.js driver version and mongodb server version. Go to mongo shell and type db.version(), the result is your mongodb version.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not using the mongo shell. I'm using node to run the program. Those are two different things right?

Comment: Yes ofcourse they are, but still you could open mongo shell from the terminal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I don't even have the mongo shell installed. I'll just look into other ways of solving the issue. I don't think I can use `watch`, every example I've seen online uses the Mongo Shell. I'll look more into it tomorrow.

Comment: I am not sure why you don't have mongo shell installed, since it comes by default on mongo server installation. And also why do you think watching the db is not an option for you? I feel it is the best option according to your requirement compared to continously querying a db which is bad approach in so many ways.

Comment: Well I never installed a mongo server either. I just use [the official mlab website](https://mlab.com/). In case you are curious, the version on there says `mongod version: 3.6.6 (MMAPv1)`. What I meant in my previous message was that `watch` may be unnecessary. The idea is that there will be a continuous stream of data flowing into the database. If that is the case, how would `watch` be any better than just querying the database every 2 or 5 seconds? Either way, I think I will be using a different method to solve the problem, using python instead of node.

Comment: @JessieLSmith Well if mlab is supporting v3.6.6 mongodb, then watch should work. the use of watch is to get constant updates and not waiting for results to come in after you do a query which you will be doing every certain number of time period.